# Script or way to check localizatons against code

Tags: xcode, localizable.strings, xcode-project

I have this app that suffered several modifications and more localizations were added over time.

Is there any way to check the Localizable.strings files for the several languages against the code to see what localizations are missing on the strings files or not being used anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

Add this option

```
-NSShowNonLocalizedStrings YES
```

as a launch argument to your app on xcode.